# Is there a name for the fear of being hit by a meteorite?

Tags: single-word-requests, phobias

I just finished reading the article [*60 Years Ago Today: The Day A Meteorite Hit Ann Hodges*](http://www.slate.com/blogs/bad_astronomy/2014/11/30/sylacauga_meteorite_60th_anniversary_of_a_human_hit_by_a_space_rock.html) (*Bad Astronomy* blog, Phil Plait)
and I couldn't help wondering what the medical term for the fear of this would be...

Comment: Since this is similar to the fear of being hit by an asteroid, a possible term would be *Umbrella purchaser* (although this is not a single word)

Comment: The medical term for this fear would be "delusional paranoia".

Comment: @DanBron - No if you are Joe Btfsplk.

Comment: @Hot, just because you're paranoid doesn't mean they aren't out to get you.  Just scheming up there, in the Oort Cloud.  I know what you're up to, up there! *shakes fist defiantly*

Comment: It's a medical condition only when it's an irrational fear. Since there is no word for it, it must mean that the fear is rational. QED

Comment: Chicken-littleism.

Comment: The condition is known technically as 'chickenlittleosis'.

Comment: Getting killed in a car accident is a rational fear. But fear of   being killed by a dead driver whose pacemaker's batteries went dead while driving a model 1948 Packard sedan is irrational.

Comment: Yeah, everyone knows that the 1948 models were all abducted by aliens.

Comment: I want to say *meteoritis*, but that's the skin condition you get after a meteorite streaks past you. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

There is ***meteorophobia*** for the fear of meteors or meteorites. It obviously covers the fear of being hit by a meteorite also. The word *meteor* comes from French *meteores* and Latin *meteora*, and  ultimately from Ancient Greek *μετέωρα* (*metéōra*); thus, this phobia word is properly formed in regard to its Latin and Greek origins as well.

> Meteorophobia is the fear of meteors. The fear is almost always triggered after learning about the meteors and their potential devastating affects of hitting the Earth. Sufferers of meteorophobia would constantly keep an eye on the sky while not be in the building, while more severe sufferers would want to go deep underground that may offer some protection from meteorite strikes if they couldn't get out of the way. - [*phobia.fandom.com*](https://phobia.fandom.com/wiki/Meteorophobia)

*Meteorophobia* is also listed in *[Oxford Dictionary of Psychology](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Dictionary_of_Psychology/UDnvBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22meteorophobia%22&pg=PA845&printsec=frontcover)* (by Andrew M. Colman) under the appendix 'Phobias and Phobic Stimuli'; which includes an additional sense in relation to the figurative sense of the word *meteor*:

> **meteorophobia** Meteors or one's success being short lived (overnight success). [From English *meteor*]

Note: This person can be called a *neurotic* also because it is an extremely rare event to worry about.

Comment: Is _meteorophobia_ recognised by a recognised authority?

Comment: It is in [_Oxford Dictionary of Psychology_](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Dictionary_of_Psychology/UDnvBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22meteorophobia%22&pg=PA845&printsec=frontcover) by Andrew M. Colman. You can find _meteorophobia_ in many other sources in Google and Google Books as well. The word is not in _OED_ yet but one can request to submit a new word in _OED_.

Comment: That seems a respectable source; answers are far better when they contain such.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't one. Oxford dictionary lists words for fear of comets (cometophobia) and stars (siderophobia) but I guess there aren't enough people afraid of getting conked on the head by meteorites or space junk to coin a phrase, yet...

Answer (score -1):

As a record in folklore, there's always Chicken Little (the sky is falling!) - who just needed a word to pathologize his preoccupation with & fear of empty vastness. (And who knows what it might throw at him.)

Comment: How does this answer the question?